# How to save 100+ Heart of pine floor with no subfloor

Tags: hardwood-floor

We have “Heart of pine” wood floors from 1907 (original to the home) and it’s all throughout the home but previous owners put either carpet over it in most the rooms except the living room, hallway and one smaller bedroom. The floors have no subfloor and bend and move when you walk on some spots. We are unsure to go about fixing these. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the floor joists accessible, can you see them from underneath?  The wood floor should be thick enough, but do need the support from the joists.  Too small joists, a couple of crack joists, or too great of a span might be the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fixing the joists should not be too hard if they are the problem.  Sanding and refinishing a beautiful wood floor I will leave to professionals.  If you can post pictures or just measurements of the joist and open span that will help.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what is causing the soft spots:

1. Too much distance from joist to joist (the span). The only way to correct this is by installing new joists between the old ones, and this requires either access from below (removing a ceiling, from basement, etc.), or from above (removing the floors, which risks damaging the wood.)
2. The joists are rotten, damaged, sagging, etc. Depending on the severity, this could be fixed by shimming the pine boards, or might involve a full rebuilding of the floor structure.

Both options require somehow accessing the structural elements to see what's going on. If you remove the floors from above, you might as well install subflooring. This will give you the support the floor needs. You can then try to salvage the floors.

To salvage a very old floor to high standards will require at the very least, professional sanding, and at most, straightening the structure, installing new subfloors, remilling the boards to make sure they are all the same thickness, reinstalling, and sanding. This is why so many people just cover them with carpet or vinyl. This is not me recommending that wood floors be covered: I hate both vinyl floors and hate carpet even more, and will only live in a place with real wood floors. But it's understandable why some people can only afford to cover them.